# Update TextView from Thread only updating after Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments, textview

I am trying to make a book alike application which has pictures and text in it. I have used fragments for this and have added a voice over which starts when a fragment page is viewable and stops when it is not viewable.

I am now trying to highlight a word as it is said in the voice over. This is my code so far

In the fragment:

```
    @Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    // Make sure that we are currently visible
    if (this.isVisible()) {

        if(MainActivity.soundOn){
            if(!MainActivity.mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                try {
                    MainActivity.mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                MainActivity.mediaPlayer.start();
                MainActivity.start(getActivity(), sentence);
            }

            //MainActivity.test(sentence);
            MainActivity.mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    //MainActivity.start();
                }
            });
        }
        // If we are becoming invisible, then...
        if (!isVisibleToUser || !MainActivity.soundOn) { 
            stopPlaying(getActivity());
        }

    }
}
```

in the main activity:

```
public static void start(Activity activity, Sentence sent){
    //textControl.start();
    try{
        player = new Player(activity);
        player.set(sent, textControl);

        textControl.draw(sent, sent.words.get(0));

                    //while the mediaplayer is playing the voice over
        while(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            player.run();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The Thread, I have removed most of the code for testing and readablitly:

```
    class Player extends Thread{

public int time;
public TextController control;
public int i = 1;
TextView tv;

private WeakReference<Activity> mActivity;
private Sentence sentence = null;

public Player(Activity activity) {
    mActivity = new WeakReference<Activity>(activity);
}

public void set(Sentence _sentence, TextController _control){
    sentence = _sentence;
    control = _control;
}


@Override
public void run()
{

    final Activity activity = mActivity.get();

    tv = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                    tv.setText("Testing");
                                //other stuff
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want to know why the code "tv.setText("Testing");" won't update the textview right after its execution? Instead it updates the textview sometime after the method setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) has finished.

I am also open to suggestions on better ways to do this.

If you would like more background info into the task and problem please feel free to ask as I have left it quite brief, thank you!

XML for fragment with textView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:onClick="toggleAction">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/fragment1"
    android:textSize="50sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You didn't post your XML so I don't know what your width and height look like on your TextView, but depending on how you do layout, TextView may or may not perform an invalidate() call when the text is changed. Try calling tv.invalidate() after you change the text and see if that does it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but this did not work, I have also added the fragments xml for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not fix this issue using this Thread and thus tried using a AsyncTask. This worked very well by updating the TextView in the onProgressUpdate

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Spannable... result){
    view.setText(result[0]);
    view.invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you're running this within a `Thread`. Once you mention this word that frightens lots of people, you have to be aware that instead of having just one execution way, you have now some more (as many as threads you have). That means that each thread won't execute its code as if it were just the UI thread, one might be accostumed to expect that the code is run secuentially, but now each of those `Thread`s have a *priority* and they're running concurrently, and also keep in mind that there might be elements like `synchronized` methods/instances which block (temporarily) the execution of some pieces of code which will make you doubt about why does some command execute later or sooner than it "should".

Having said that, once when you enter into the multithreading world, though it is very versatile and very powerful, you have to keep in mind that some portions of your code must be **synchronized** in order to get the expected result. One way of doing this is, as I mentioned previously, the `synchronized` reserved word. You may assign it to both methods and instances. A very good reading might be found [there](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html) about that.

Other ways of synchronizing execution workflows is choosing some data types that natively implement concurrency access/insertion/modification/deletion controls, so you don't have to bare with this and avoid huge headaches of why are you getting Concurrency Exceptions. You may find a list of those structures [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).

You have other mechanisms of synchronization. Two of them, and probably the most popular are `Semaphore`s and `CountDownLatch`es. I personally prefer the last one, as it gives a big versatility to handle inter-class and even inter-method synchronization. A very good example might be found on the [developer reference page](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

Comment: Thank you for this information, it is very much appreciated, but unfortunately it has not seemed to fix the problem.